# Error: [$injector:unpr] when injecting services in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I know similar questions about this error has been asked numerous times before in SO, and I have read the answers, but as far as I am able to see, my code is designed correctly. But it can't of course since I get this error .. My app has a few services and and a few controllers, and all of them work together apart from one specific service/controller for some reason. I have been able to strip down the code to a minimum, shown below. The error appears when the TestController is triggered from the view with `.. ng-controller="TestController" ..`and the error message in the Chrome console is:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20Loyper
>       at Error (native)..

I have been struggling with this for some time, and can't see that this service (Loyper) and controller (TestController) is defined otherwise than those that are working, in terms of injections. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var app = angular.module('testapp', [
"ngRoute",
"mobile-angular-ui"

]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'TestController'
}).
when('/loyper', {
    templateUrl: 'loyper.html',
    controller: 'LoypeController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});

$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

}]);

app.service('Loyper', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

var cached = false;
var loyper = {};
var message;

return {
    foo: 'bar'
}

}]);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'Loyper', function($scope, Loyper) {

angular.extend($scope, {
    getLoyper: function() {
        return Loyper.foo;
    }

});

$scope.loypelist = $scope.getLoyper();

}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A service can't be injected with `$scope`, since a service is a singleton, whereas each controller, and many directives, have their own scope. The problem is thus at this line:

```
app.service('Loyper', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

which should be

```
app.service('Loyper', ['$http', function($http) {
```

And in fact, since your service doesn't use $http, it shouldn't take $http as argument either.

Comment: Thanks @jb-nizet! But $rootScope could make sense to inject in a service, or? I am pretty sure I have seen it. Btw, $http is used by my service, I just stripped out the code.

Comment: Yes, $rootScope can be injected in a service.